# Why can't I bold just part of a string in Swift with NSMutableString?

Tags: ios, swift

The problem is that I can color half of the string but I cannot bold that half of the string.

Here's the code

```
 var string = "blah blah blah blah blah"
  var range = NSRange(location:0, length: 4)
//Apply to the label
myMutableString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName,
                             value: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize([X size]), range: range)

myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                             value: UIColor.green(),
                             range: range)
UILabel.text.attributedText = myMutableString
```

Any ideas why bolding bolds the entire string instead of just the first "blah"? Only the first "blah" is colored green.

Comment: Did you mean NSMutableAttributedString? Try giving a fully contained working example, your example is using variables and things that we don't have access to.

Comment: What is `myMutableString`? Where is it set/initialized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just posting an answer because it was fun to use the playgrounds interactively and see the UILabel changing in real time.

```
import UIKit

let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 100))
let text = "black green small"
var mutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)

let textCount = text.utf16.count // Thanks OOPer
mutableString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName,
    value: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20),
    range: NSRange(location:0, length: textCount*2/3)
)

mutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
    value: UIColor.greenColor(),
    range: NSRange(textCount/3..<textCount)
)

label.attributedText = mutableString
label
```

[image: Image of interactive .playground file]

---

To please OOPer, I learned a little bit more about character indexes

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

extension String { // tools
    func characterIndex(ofFraction fraction: Float) -> String.CharacterView.Index {
        let amountOfCharacters = Int(Float(self.characters.count) * fraction)
        return self.characters.startIndex.advancedBy(amountOfCharacters, limit: self.characters.endIndex)
    }

    func utf16Index(characterIndex index: String.CharacterView.Index) -> String.UTF16View.Index {
        return String.UTF16View.Index(index, within: self.utf16)
    }

    func utf16Offset(toIndex index: String.UTF16View.Index) -> String.UTF16View.Index.Distance {
        return self.utf16.startIndex.distanceTo(index)
    }
}

extension String { // convenience
    func utf16Offset(ofFraction fraction: Float) -> String.UTF16View.Index.Distance {
        let correctIndexOfFraction = self.characterIndex(ofFraction: fraction)
        let translatedToUTF16 = self.utf16Index(characterIndex: correctIndexOfFraction)
        let absolutePosition = self.utf16Offset(toIndex: translatedToUTF16)
        return absolutePosition
    }
}

func paintedString(text: String) -> NSAttributedString {
    let mutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)

    let firstTwoThirds = 0..<text.utf16Offset(ofFraction: 2/3)
    let lastTwoThirds = text.utf16Offset(ofFraction: 1/3)..<text.utf16.count

    mutableString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName,
                               value: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(30),
                               range: NSRange(firstTwoThirds)
    )

    mutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                               value: UIColor.greenColor(),
                               range: NSRange(lastTwoThirds)
    )

    return mutableString
}

func paintedLabel(text text: String) -> UILabel {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50))
    label.attributedText = paintedString(text)
    return label
}

paintedLabel(text: "black green small")
paintedLabel(text: "")
```

[image: New correct version executed in Playground]

Comment: `NSMutableAttributedString` uses UTF-16 based counts and offsets. You should use `text.utf16.count` than `text.characters.count`.

Comment: Thanks OOPer, I didn't know that! (I edited my answer)

Comment: Thanks for responding, but your edited code is not perfect. Because `textCount*2/3` or `textCount/3` may be an invalid index, when your `text` contains some non-BMP characters. See what happens with `let text = "\u{1F110}\u{1F111}\u{1F112}\u{1F113}\u{1F114}"`.

Comment: Dammit you're strict, there you go, I edited it again. BTW, you just forced me to learn a lot, thank you ;)

Comment: Great! Thanks for updating. Your way of doing it seems to be stricter than I have in mind. Hope your effort may help many developers working on it. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your code not working because the string should be assigned to the myMutableString even before the attributes are set to the  myMutableString

```
var string = "blah blah blah blah blah"

myMutableString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName,
                             value: UIFont.boldSystem ..
```

The working code based on your requirement :

```
var string = "blah blah blah blah blah"

let myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string)
 var range = NSRange(location:0, length: 4)
 //Apply to the label
 myMutableString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName,
                              value: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(10), range: range)

 myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                              value: UIColor.blueColor(),
                              range: range)
```